# When adding prefix in media URL category image upload gets affected in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

When I add prefix **fs_** in media URL of s3 bucket then getting issue with category image save.

- When I select image for category image and custom image for first time it gets saved.
  In **catalog_category_entity_varchar** the **Value** for image is **/media/catalog/category/demo.jpg**
- When I click on save second time then image gets disappear from admin. In **catalog_category_entity_varchar** the **Value** for image is **fs_/media/catalog/category/demo.jpg**
- When I click on save third time image still disappear from admin. In **catalog_category_entity_varchar** the value for image is **null**.
- In configuration :

  web/unsecure/base_media_url "https://WHATEVER.amazonaws.com/fs_/media/"

  web/secure/base_media_url "https://WHATEVER.amazonaws.com/fs_/media/"

The issue is for category section only and for category image and other custom image attribute.

When I remove **fs_** prefix then it working fine.

Please help.